# Docker logs --follow in tmux stops after some time

Tags: docker, logging, tmux

I have a `tmux` setup which shows various `docker logs` with the `--follow` flag, so that I can connect to the session and easily see the realtime logs of the containers.

My issue is that after a couple of hours (days on some low verbosity logs), or possibly after a couple of KB's of logs have passed by in a pane, it simply stops showing new log entries until I ctrl-c in that pane and run the `docker logs` command again.

I'm using

```
'log_config': {
  'log-type': 'json-file',
  'max-size': '10m',
},
```

in the containers, so I thought that maybe this is related to some kind of log file rollover, but this seems to happen earlier than after 10MB of new log data has been generated. Maybe similar to this issue [Detect log file rotation (while watching log file for modification)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44407834/277267)

It doesn't exit. It just stops showing new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in Docker's logging driver

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39235

The workaround is to add `max-file` with a value above 1.

```
'log_config': {
  'log-type': 'json-file',
  'max-size': '10m',
  'max-file': '2',
},
```